# Easiest way to parse gem-style command line arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, command-line-arguments

I would like to implement gem-style console app, and when I say `gem` (or `apt-get` etc) style, I mean that it will have invocation syntax like:

```
program.rb verb [argument] [--options ...]
```

For example

```
greeter.rb say "Hello world" --bold
```

I have used `optparse` but I think it is not suitable for anything except `--option` style arguments. Am I wrong about it or there is more suitable library to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest not to parse from scratch; I suggest to use [**GLI**](http://rubygems.org/gems/gli) by which you can provide (via its DSL) a git like interface to your users. Get started [here](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli/wiki) to see how it works.

You might also be interested in looking at a real (**humble**) implementation in a project of mine. Check these files:

- https://github.com/empo/RuGPost/blob/master/bin/rugpost
- https://github.com/empo/RuGPost/blob/master/lib/rugpost/commands.rb
- https://github.com/empo/RuGPost/blob/master/lib/rugpost/commands/post_commands.rb
- https://github.com/empo/RuGPost/blob/master/lib/rugpost/commands/project_commands.rb